# How to sum appearances in columns with pandas without lambda

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I have the following dataframe

```
    a    b    c    d    e 
0   0    0   -1    1   -1
1   0    1   -1    1   -1
2  -1    0   -1    1    1
3  -1    1    1   -1    1
4   1    0    1   -1    1  
5   1    0    0    0    1 
6   1    1    0    0   -1 
7   1    1   -1    0    0
```

For each numbers that appears in a,b,c,d,e, I want to sum and store in a column the amount of times that it appears in a row, so the result should be something like this:

```
    a    b    c    d    e  Sum1  Sum0  Sum_1
0   0    0   -1    1   -1    1    2     2
1   0    1   -1    1   -1    2    1     2 
2  -1    0   -1    1    1    2    1     2
3  -1    1    1   -1    1    3    0     2
4   1    0    1   -1    1    3    1     1
5   1    0    0    0    1    2    3     0
6   1   -1    0    0   -1    1    2     2
7   1    1   -1   -1    0    2    1     2
```

So in the first row, the number "1" appears once in a,b,c,d,e, so we store that in Sum1 column. Then, number "0" appears two times, and we store that in Sum0, and number "-1" appears 2 times and we store it in Sum_1.

How could this columns be calculated, without using lambda functions (to get better performance)? I guess that numpy is involved here but I don't get how to do it

Comment: Would there be only -1, 0, 1?

Comment: At this moment, yes. Although probably I'd like to use other values in the future, a solution with only -1, 0, and 1 is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `get_dummies`

```
df=df.astype(str)
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0)
Out[667]: 
   -1  0  1
0   2  2  1
1   2  1  2
2   2  1  2
3   2  0  3
4   1  1  3
5   0  3  2
6   1  2  2
7   1  2  2
```

More info

```
pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('Sum')],1)
Out[669]: 
    a  b   c   d   e  Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0   0  0  -1   1  -1      2     2     1
1   0  1  -1   1  -1      2     1     2
2  -1  0  -1   1   1      2     1     2
3  -1  1   1  -1   1      2     0     3
4   1  0   1  -1   1      1     1     3
5   1  0   0   0   1      0     3     2
6   1  1   0   0  -1      1     2     2
7   1  1  -1   0   0      1     2     2
```

***Another method maybe solve but do not need convert to str.***

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.value_counts(),1).fillna(0)

Out[674]: 
    -1    0    1
0  2.0  2.0  1.0
1  2.0  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  1.0  2.0
3  2.0  0.0  3.0
4  1.0  1.0  3.0
5  0.0  3.0  2.0
6  1.0  2.0  2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: The best part about this answer is that it works for a million values just as well as it would work for [-1, 0, 1].

Comment: Nice, and `pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).reindex(columns=[-1,0,1], fill_value=0)` if interested in subset of values only.

Comment: Also, a question arises; would this work if columns a,b,c,d,e have the same name? (because the dataframe is a pd.concat of other df, all of them with the same column name)

Comment: @PandemicCode same name column always create this type of issue, better rename it

Comment: @Wen your code works beautifully. Although the other answers are also good, this is a really elegant one.

Comment: @PandemicCode glad it help ,have nice day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create boolean mask and count it - `True`s are process like `1`:

```
m1 = df == 1
m0 = df == 0
m_1 = df == -1
df['Sum1'] = m1.sum(1)
df['Sum0'] = m0.sum(1)
df['Sum_1'] = m_1.sum(1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  Sum1  Sum0  Sum_1
0  0  0 -1  1 -1     1     2      2
1  0  1 -1  1 -1     2     1      2
2 -1  0 -1  1  1     2     1      2
3 -1  1  1 -1  1     3     0      2
4  1  0  1 -1  1     3     1      1
5  1  0  0  0  1     2     3      0
6  1  1  0  0 -1     2     2      1
7  1  1 -1  0  0     2     2      1
```

---

General solution with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .sum(level=0, axis=1)
         .add_prefix('Sum'))
print (df1)
   Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0      2     2     1
1      2     1     2
2      2     1     2
3      2     0     3
4      1     1     3
5      0     3     2
6      1     2     2
7      1     2     2

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0  0  0 -1  1 -1      2     2     1
1  0  1 -1  1 -1      2     1     2
2 -1  0 -1  1  1      2     1     2
3 -1  1  1 -1  1      2     0     3
4  1  0  1 -1  1      1     1     3
5  1  0  0  0  1      0     3     2
6  1  1  0  0 -1      1     2     2
7  1  1 -1  0  0      1     2     2
```

Idea for better performance of `Zero` solution - compare `numpy array` and instead static values is possible use unique values by [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
all_vals = np.unique(df.values)
arr = df.values
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):(arr == v).sum(1) for v in all_vals})) 
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e  Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0  0  0 -1  1 -1      2     2     1
1  0  1 -1  1 -1      2     1     2
2 -1  0 -1  1  1      2     1     2
3 -1  1  1 -1  1      2     0     3
4  1  0  1 -1  1      1     1     3
5  1  0  0  0  1      0     3     2
6  1  1  0  0 -1      1     2     2
7  1  1 -1  0  0      1     2     2
```

**Timings**

```
np.random.seed(234)
N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(N,5)), columns=list('abcde')) - 1
print (df)

#wen's solution 1
In [49]: %timeit pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str).stack()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('Sum')],1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.21 s per loop

#wen's solution 2
In [56]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x : x.value_counts(),1).fillna(0)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 35s per loop
```

---

```
#jezrael's solution 2
In [50]: %timeit df.join((pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(level=0, axis=1).add_prefix('Sum')))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.14 s per loop

#jezrael's solution 1
In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: m1 = df == 1
    ...: m0 = df == 0
    ...: m_1 = df == -1
    ...: df['Sum1'] = m1.sum(1)
    ...: df['Sum0'] = m0.sum(1)
    ...: df['Sum_1'] = m_1.sum(1)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 50.6 ms per loop
```

---

```
#zero's solution1
In [51]: %timeit df.assign(**{'Sum{}'.format(v):df.eq(v).sum(1) for v in [1, 0, -1]})
10 loops, best of 3: 39.8 ms per loop

#zero's solution2    
In [52]: %timeit df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):df.eq(v).sum(1) for v in [1, 0, -1]}))
10 loops, best of 3: 39.6 ms per loop
```

---

```
#zero&jezrael's solution1 
In [53]: %timeit df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):(df.values == v).sum(1) for v in np.unique(df.values)}))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.8 ms per loop

#zero&jezrael's solution2    
In [54]: %timeit df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):(df.values == v).sum(1) for v in [0, 1, -1]}))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop

#if many columns and more unique values is possible convert to numpy array outside loop

def f1(df):
    all_vals = np.unique(df.values)
    arr = df.values
    return df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):(arr == v).sum(1) for v in all_vals}))

def f2(df):
    arr = df.values
    return df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):(arr == v).sum(1) for v in [0, 1, -1]}))

print (f1(df))
print (f2(df))

#zero&jezrael's solution3
In [58]: %timeit (f1(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop

#zero&jezrael's solution4
In [59]: %timeit (f2(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop
```

Comment: If you run `Sum0` and then `Sum1`, this might not work. Since `df` is overwritten and value check is done on all of `df`

Comment: Keeping in mind that this becomes inconvenient if you need to sum more than just 3 values. Zero's answer is a sort of generalisation of this.

Comment: New? Looks a lot like Wen's answer, with the only difference being join... ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - and removeing stack ;)

Comment: I suspect, this would be inefficient, string conversion, and then mxn explode of values, ..?

Comment: @Zero - Yes, it is possible. But if need general solution unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [62]: df.assign(**{'Sum{}'.format(v):df.eq(v).sum(1) for v in [1, 0, -1]})
Out[62]:
   a  b  c  d  e  Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0  0  0 -1  1 -1      2     2     1
1  0  1 -1  1 -1      2     1     2
2 -1  0 -1  1  1      2     1     2
3 -1  1  1 -1  1      2     0     3
4  1  0  1 -1  1      1     1     3
5  1  0  0  0  1      0     3     2
6  1  1  0  0 -1      1     2     2
7  1  1 -1  0  0      1     2     2
```

Same as

```
In [72]: df.join(pd.DataFrame({'Sum{}'.format(v):df.eq(v).sum(1) for v in [1, 0, -1]}))
Out[72]:
   a  b  c  d  e  Sum-1  Sum0  Sum1
0  0  0 -1  1 -1      2     2     1
1  0  1 -1  1 -1      2     1     2
2 -1  0 -1  1  1      2     1     2
3 -1  1  1 -1  1      2     0     3
4  1  0  1 -1  1      1     1     3
5  1  0  0  0  1      0     3     2
6  1  1  0  0 -1      1     2     2
7  1  1 -1  0  0      1     2     2
```